# how to send encrypted data in a post request?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to create a post request to a recaptcha site, it works in burp suite, but not in python requests.

I open the site that creates this request, send this request to repeater BurpSuite, and it gives a normal response. if I make the same request in python, it will not give a normal response, the request clearly has some strange data. I looked at the request through wireshark and copied data from there and sent it through python, but still nothing works. Here is a picture of the request in BurpSuite
[BurpSuite req](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBirZ.jpg)

i check it in wireshark and get this:
[burp suite req in shark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KDGH.jpg)

i try copy data and send it in python

```
import httpx
from requests.structures import CaseInsensitiveDict
headers=CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers['Host']='www.google.com'
headers['User-Agent']='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv'
headers['Accept']='*/*'
headers['Accept-Language']='ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'
headers['Accept-Encoding']='gzip, deflate'
headers['Content-Type']='application/x-protobuffer'
headers['Content-Length']='8636'
headers['Origin']='https://www.google.com'
headers['Referer']='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&k=6Ld74p4lAAAAACY-Z0TzBFkJgWu1DI9siriJqjOG&co=aHR0cHM6Ly9rb250by5nYXpldGEucGw6NDQz&hl=ru&v=sNQO7xVld1CuA2hfFHvkpVL-&size=invisible&cb=fncw2wg8imh3'
headers['Sec-Fetch-Dest']='empty'
headers['Sec-Fetch-Mode']='cors'
headers['Sec-Fetch-Site']='same-origin'
headers['Te']='trailers'
data='''(data from wireshark)'''
r=httpx.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6Ld74p4lAAAAACY-Z0TzBFkJgWu1DI9siriJqjOG',headers=headers,data=data)
print(r.text)
```

but it not work
[python wireshark req](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwzD2.jpg)

Comment: Could you include the code that you've written to send the request? Additionally, what kind of response are you getting?

Comment: Could you include the response you get from the server when you send your request with python? The response code and body would both be useful information.

Comment: Please [do not post code as pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7877117)